# Laravel Homestead "This page isn't working" ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE out of nowhere

Tags: laravel-5, homestead

I have a per-project install of Laravel Homestead and up until today it's been accessible in the browser all the time ok. Now all of the sudden the page isn't sending any data. Last thing I did was seed the database [successfully]. Why might this be? I tried dump-autoload and cache:clear

UPDATE: I did have two installations of laravel/homestead (3.1.0 & 4.0.0), the outdated one wasn't removed when I updated. So I destroyed and removed the old one, up'ed the new one, ssh and it's still reflecting the same filesystem but still not working.

&UPDATE: I also [tried and failed to install ngrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378263/how-can-i-install-ngrok-on-os-x-el-capitan) prior to this happening but I'm pretty sure I'd worked in homestead since that

Comment: can you try "vagrant reload" ?

Comment: doesn't fix anything

Comment: How do you connect localhost ? like localhost:portnumber or 127.0.0.1:portnumber ? Can you try another ?

Comment: homestead.dev same result when i try the IP it's pointed to and like I said they normally work I also tried changing it to something different just produces the same result

Answer (score 0):

I updated VirtualBox now all is well.